# How to += string with sql query using php?

Tags: php, sql

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '0-' in ... Stack trace: #0 ...(68): mysqli->query('UPDATE `Results...') #1 {main} thrown in ... on line 68

That's the error I am getting with the ellipses representing the file pathway.

The php I have:

```php
for($i = 1; $i < $maxQuestions; $i++){
    $answer = $_POST["question$i"] == "Yes" ? "1-" : "0-";
    $connection->query("UPDATE `Results` 
    SET `question$i` = `question$i` + '$answer'
    WHERE `ID` = '$id'");
}
```

The problem is with the `` SET `question$i` = `question$i` + '$answer' `` as I am trying to basically keep a history of the question's answers. For example, I may want the stored data to go from "0-" to "0-1-". How do you += a string with php/sql?

**EDIT:**
I have tried `` SET `question$i` = concat(`question$i` + '$answer') `` and I am getting the same error.

Comment: Use `||` or `concat()` to concatenate strings.

Comment: which data type is  `question$i`  column???

Comment: @scaisEdge It is of type "text".

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I tried that but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: `+` is the sum arithmetic operator in all SQL dialects I'm aware of.

Comment: The fact that you have numbers at the end of your column names means you should normalise your database.

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to

```php
for($i = 1; $i < $maxQuestions; $i++){
    $answer = $_POST["question$i"] == "yes" ? "1-" : "0-";
    $qColumn = "question" . strval($i);

    $questionData = $data["question$i"] . $answer;

    $connection->query("UPDATE `Results` 
    SET `$qColumn` = '$questionData'
    WHERE `ID` = '$id'");
}
```

This worked, but I'm still not sure why my initial code did not work. If someone could post a better answer/solution and why my initial code didn't work, please do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In mysql You can do it  dierctly using concat this way

```
 SET `question$i` =concat(`question$i`,  '$answer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have column names ending with numbers because this is an indicator that your schema is not correct. You should normalise the database and have questions as a separate tables joined to your results table. Your results should not be concatenated into a single column either. Have a separate row for each result.

However, if you want to achieve this with your current set-up you could use `CONCAT()`. The query should look similar to this:

```
$types = '';
$setString = [];
$values = [];
for($i = 1; $i < $maxQuestions; $i++){
    // concat types
    $types .= 's';
    // gather values
    $values[] = isset($_POST["question$i"]) ? "1-" : "0-";
    // build SET statement
    $columnName = "question" . $i;
    $setString[] =  $columnName.' = CONCAT('.$columnName.', ?)';

}
$sql = "UPDATE Results SET ".implode(', ', $setString).' WHERE ID = ?';
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
$stmt->execute();
```